# How to create index for postgresql jsonb field (array data) and text field

Tags: postgresql

Please let me know how to create index for below query.

```
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE identifiers @>
      '[{"systemName": "SAP", "systemReference": "33557"}]'
  AND country_code = 'IN';
```

`identifiers` is jsonb type and data is as below.

```
[{"systemName": "ERP", "systemReference": "TEST"}, {"systemName": "FEED", "systemReference": "2733"}, {"systemName": "SAP", "systemReference": "33557"}]
```

`country_code` is varchar type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a GIN index on `identifiers` ..

```
CREATE INDEX customers_identifiers_idx ON customers 
USING GIN(identifiers);
```

.. or a composite index with `identifiers` and `country_code`.

```
CREATE INDEX customers_country_code_identifiers_idx ON customers 
USING GIN(identifiers,country_code gin_trgm_ops);
```

The second option will depend on the values distribution of `country_code`.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=48981e475e4e659cd43cdc9682ffa535)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `gin` index for `jsonb` typed columns in `Postgresql`. `gin` index has built-in operator classes to handle jsonb operators. Learn more about gin index here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/gin-intro.html

For varchar types, btree index is good enough.